# Spark SQL json error

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

I have tried to create jsonrdd using sql context but getting the below error.. I have placed the code and error below.. please suggest..

My code:

```
rdd1=sqlContext.jsonRDD('/idn/home/ijamalmo/ibfiles/datafiles/sampledata.json')
```

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/context.py",
>   line 442, in jsonRDD
>
> ```
> keyed = rdd.mapPartitions(func)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mapPartitions'

Answer (score 0):

`jsonRDD` is not a pyspark function. You want:

```
rdd1 = sqlContext.read.json('fileLoc').rdd
```

Comment: sqlCon=SQLContext(sc)
rdd1=sqlCon.jsonFile('smapledata.json')

This command is executing without any error. But when i tried to print the schema or printing the data it is thrwoing the error

rdd1.printSchema()
rdd1.collect()
Please advice